# Let $K = \mathbb C(X)$, $\sigma: X \mapsto \xi X$ and $\tau: X \mapsto X^{-1}$. Find number of elements in $G$ generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K = \mathbb C(X)$ (**denote the field of fractions of $\mathbb C[X]$**) and consider the following automorphisms of $K$:

$\sigma: X \mapsto \xi X$ and $\tau: X \mapsto X^{-1}$, where $\xi$ denote the primitive root of $1$ of order $3$.

I want to check the relations in group $G$ generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$:

$\sigma^3 = 1 = \tau^2$ and $\tau \sigma \tau = \sigma^{-1}$.

and **find the number of elements in $G$**.

I know $\sigma^3(X) = \sigma(\sigma(\sigma(X))) = \sigma(\sigma(\xi X)) = \sigma(\sigma(\xi)\sigma(X)) = \sigma(\sigma(\xi) \xi X))$.

But how can I determine that $\sigma(\xi) = \xi$ such that I can conclude $\sigma^3: X \mapsto X$ ?

I've the same problem regarding $\tau^2 = 1$.

Comment: I think it is assumed that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ fix elements in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @awllower i think so... unless otherwise stated...

Comment: @awllower, I guess you are right, that's also my idea. But this is not stated in the problem formulation. I guess I will contact the author.

Comment: Will it help if I say that $\mathbb C(X)$ denote the field of fractions of $\mathbb C[X]$ ?

Comment: I think more contexts help in determining if $\sigma$ is assumed to fix $\mathbb C$ or not.